# Change video being played in HTML5 video

Tags: video, html

I'm using the  tags in HTML5 to play a video on a web browser... (and I'm very impressed with this new feature)

Is there the functionality to change the video being played through Javascript? Say when I select another video from a list, a Javascript function would be called which would contain something on the lines of `MyVideo.VideoLocation = //location of new video to be played`. Is this possible please?

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Comment: look at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703203/html5-video-change-multiple-sources

nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 24):

Webkit requires that you call "load()" after changing the source:

```
videoTag.src = "newVideo";
videoTag.load();
videoTag.play();
```

Apple has [a useful tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW5).

Comment: You sir are my hero!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution, tested on Ipad/Iphone/Webkit/Firefox

```
<script>

function playNext(path,target)
{
target[0].src=path;
target[0].load();
target[0].play();
}

playNext("pathToMovie",$('#video_1'));

</script>
```

Comment: target[0].load();target[0].play(); will do nothing on iPhone

Comment: It shouldn't have done. iOS doesn't allow videos to be played automatically or via script. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12496184/989920

Answer (score 0):

The property to be used:

```
videoTag.src
```

If it doesn't auto-start playing after that:

```
videoTag.play()
```