# Changing video src via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple videos on my website that has multiple codecs for multiple browsers.

```
<video id="video2" width="480" height="270">
<source src="movies/vid2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
<source src="movies/vid2.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="movies/vid2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

I only need to show one video at a time. so i have

```
onClick="changevid(A)
```

the onClick is working fine, changing the vids. but how do i change all 3 of them?

vid1.ogv
vid1.webm
vid1.mp4

```
i can only change 1 by doing
var A = 'movies/vid1.mp4';

function changevid(q){
    document.getElementById('video2').setAttribute('src', q);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If it helps, i saw this link but I'm not sure if it's the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703203/html5-video-change-multiple-sources

Comment: Is jQuery OK for a solution?

Comment: Try `Element.src =` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function changevid(q){
  E('video2').src = q;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm not that good with programming yet, so i don't really understand the code. what's bod for? and it doesn't seem to change formats?

Comment: Just showing you how variables work. I put `document` in `doc` so `doc.body` is your `<body>` tag. It's not in use here.