# HTML5 video tag autoplay on ios6 / Safari

Tags: html, ios6, html5-video

I'm attempting to build a site that will autoplay short videos (.mov) on a rotating basis. Seemed okay to HTML5 and works well with Chrome on a PC.  But when running on an iPad, the video does not autoplay, and waits for someone to click the video.  Is there not a way to autoplay?  I've attempted to invoke via javascript, but it fails.  Any suggestions are welcome.  I've confirm ios6.01 on iPad2..

The tag is as follows:

```
    <video id="vidWindow" controls="controls"
           autoplay="autoplay"  poster="images/rbc3d.png">
        <source src="videos/28497184.mp4"   />
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Comment: Still see no luck/answers...  Is there any settings/config that can be made on the receiving iPad to allow an autoplay to occur.  These are on a local network.  there's got to be a workable solution... ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you autoplay HTML5 videos on the iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad)

Comment: Also please keep in mind that behaviour like the one you like to achieve can be very annoying. For the most part if this happens on a page I visit this is my first and last time there.

Answer (score 1):

This was intentionally disabled by Apple (and for good reason). The Safari Reference Library states:

In Safari on iPhone OS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, autobuffering and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the play() method is triggered by user action.

Comment: I understand the reasoning. but I have a use case with the iPads are on an internal network and need to be fed streaming content.  Is there a setting on an iPad to allow the autoplay?

Answer (score 1):

Just add '**webkit-playsinline**' attribute to the video tag and execute the below javacript function

```
function playVideo(){
   var video = document.getElementById("vidWindow");
   video.play();
}
playVideo();
```