# Trying to play a video on iPad using HTML5 but video wont play and cant start manually

Tags: ios, html, wordpress, ipad

The website is: [Experience Map](http://www.experiencemap.com)

The video plays nicely on desktop but I cannot get it to play on iPad.

Below is the code we are using on the homepage to get the video to autostart and loop, a direct link to the file plays the video so it is not this. Any help would be great.

```
<section class="video-home">
<video width="560" height="340" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" >
<source src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/01161203_7ea3dc3247fbdda59fbf7f7435e88464.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>  
<source src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Expereince-Map_libtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
<object width="640" height="384" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="http://www.experiencemap.com/wp includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf?image=placeholder.jpg&file=/wp content/uploads/2013/06/Experience-Map-h264.mp4">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.experiencemap.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/moxieplayer.swf?image=placeholder.jpg&file=/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/01161203_7ea3dc3247fbdda59fbf7f7435e88464.mp4" />
</object>
    </video>
    </section>
```

Kind regards,

Chris

Comment: This may not be the reason it's not working, but if you look at line 1485 of the page source (the <object> tag), you'll notice that Wordpress is adding a <br /> where you've got a line return, which is breaking the <object> element. I'd try putting putting the <source> elements and <object> element all on one line and see if that helps.

Comment: Looks like the real reason is that autoplay doesn't work on iOS and Android. Source: http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response. We have removed the break and thanks for the autoplay response, I guess we will have to live with that for now.

Any other ideas on why it's still not working?

Comment: The link does say that autoplay should work on iPads running at least 6.1 which I am... any other solutions/thughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of **[Can you autoplay HTML5 videos on the iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad)**