# HTML5 Video autoplay with param

Tags: html, video, autoplay

How can I play an HTML5 video autoplay with param in URL?

For example: http://mydomain/video?autoplay=1

Is it possible for html5 video?

I Know about:  HTML5 tag,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `autoplay`:

```
 <video controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

If you want to get the argument of autoplay, lets say, with php, you can use:

url : `http://mydomain/video.php?autoplay=1`

**video.php**

```
<?php
$autoplay = "";
if($_GET['autoplay'] === "1"){

   $autoplay = "autoplay";
}

//now we can serve the video

$html5Video = <<< LOL
 <video controls $autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> 
LOL;
echo $html5Video;

?>
```

---

**NOTE:** 
`html5` video `autoplay` [isn't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21843696/797495) on most mobile browsers.

Comment: The code will be the same, you don't need to change it. It simply doesn't `autoplay`.