# Autoplay video in Mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, html5-video, autoplay

I want to play `video` and `audio` in autoplay mode, When both are ready to play.
I'm using this code.

```
 var video = false;
 var audio = false;
 video.addEventListener('canplay',function(){
    video = true;
    playall();
 });
 audio.addEventListener('canplay',function(){
    audio = true;
    playall();
 });
playall(){
  if(video && audio){
    console.log('playing start....');
    video.play();
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

This code is working fine in desktop browsers. But when I try it on mobile device it is not working. 
Here is a link where you can see it live how its working.
[Video Link](http://imube.com/watch.php?v=Kn25hijDL7c)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome/ie now supports the autoplay if muted

```
<video id="video" width="100%" controls   autoplay muted>
    <source src="<Your video src>" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can't for now as stated here :

> The auto play limitation in mobile browsers is an intentional limitation put in by the OS developers. To my knowledge, there is absolutely no way to auto play content in a mobile browser because the event that is required to trigger content play is an OS/Phone event, one which the browser itself has no control over or interaction with.

[HTML5 Video autoplay on Mobile Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499341/html5-video-autoplay-on-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Right now answering by only adding `autoplay muted` to the video tag isn't working.

For me, the easiest solution was to use the native function `play()`.

```
<video>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

for the code above use this js (if browser is really old use if statement below):

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
if ('play' in video) {
    video.play();
}
```