# HTML5 video and jQuery script not working properly on mobile devices

Tags: android, jquery, html, video

### This script is working on pc

1. I have video in my slider which works on my pc but when i tried to test my website on my smartphone(Galaxy Note 3)...it doesnt owrk...the video must play when the page loads when document is ready or active slide is video...

### Html

```
<div class="flexslider" id="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li id="slide1">
        <video id="myVideo" src="Videos/New York City - Time Lapse.mp4" style="width:100%;"></video>
        <div class="flex-caption text-center">
            <h1 class="head">Time To Grow Your Business !</h1>
            <div class="line">
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="parWrap">
                <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis.</p>
                <button type="button" class="shareHead animated flipInY">Share <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> &nbsp;Heart</button>
            </div>
           <button type="button" class="playPause">Pause</button><br>           
        </div>                  
    </li>     
    <li id="slide2">
        <img src="Images/Slider Images/image1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="flex-caption text-center">
            <h1 class="head">Time To Grow Your Business !</h1>
            <div class="line">
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="parWrap">
                <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis</p>
                <button type="button" class="shareHead animated flipInY">Share <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> &nbsp;Heart</button>
            </div>                      
        </div>                                                      
    </li>   
    <li id="slide3">
        <img src="Images/Slider Images/image2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="flex-caption text-center">
            <h1 class="head">Time To Grow Your Business !</h1>
            <div class="line">
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="parWrap">
                <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis</p>
                <button type="button" class="shareHead animated flipInY">Share <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> &nbsp;Heart</button>
            </div>
        </div>                          
    </li>
    <li id="slide4">
        <img src="Images/Slider Images/image3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="flex-caption text-center">
            <h1 class="head">Time To Grow Your Business !</h1>
            <div class="line">
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="parWrap">
                <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis.</p>
                <button type="button" class="shareHead animated flipInY">Share <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> &nbsp;Heart</button>
            </div>
        </div>                          
    </li>       
  </ul>
</div>
```

## Script ##

---

2. The video is playing when I click the play button...but how the script works 
   it must autoplay on some conditions not when i click...that works on pc properly only on mobile devices it doesnt work

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var active_id = $('.flex-active-slide').attr('id');
                //if the active slide is the video slide...  
                if( active_id == "slide1"){
                  //play the video and pause the slider
                  myVideo.play();
                  $('.flexslider').flexslider("pause");
                  //when the video has ended, go to the next slide and play the slider
                  myVideo.onended = function(){
                      $('.flexslider').flexslider("next");
                      $('.flexslider').flexslider("play");
                  }
                }  
          myVideo.pause();
          setTimeout(function () {      
             myVideo.play();
          }, 150);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay on mobile devices is disabled.

This question was already posted, and you can find expalantion here: 
[HTML5 Video autoplay on Mobile Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499341/html5-video-autoplay-on-mobile-browser)

Comment: So there is no way to play video?

Comment: No if you want to play it automatically without any user action.