# Youtube player on iPad Safari - Touch interaction with elements on top of video blocked

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, youtube, mobile-safari

When I set up a youtube player in an iframe in the normal way ( like this https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo ), and make a new html element (button) positioned over the top of youtube's iframe, any touch of the video player seems to be "caught" by the video controls so the user cannot tap the button I've made.

Removing the controls with the parameter "controls=0" solves the problem, and the user is able to tap the button. However, I need to find a way around this whilst leaving the controls on - at the moment the only option I can see is building my own controls overlay on top, which is not desirable. The fact that youtube seem to be able to grab and not grab the touch interaction would seem to prove that it is possible in some way with the JavaScript.

-not a problem on Android tablets.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad), limitations exist on iOS, where "...embedded media cannot be played automatically/programatically in Safari on iOS - the user always initiates playback."