# YouTube iFrame API hangs in buffering state after the playVideo() command on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a problem with the iFrame API on the iPad (iOS 7, Safari browser). When I try to start the video with the 'player.playVideo()' command, the player goes to black and returns a '3'-state when I call 'player.getPlayerState()' command (says it's buffering).

Hitting the big red YouTube button works, but using the 'playVideo()' command does not. This can be reproduced on Google's own YouTube API demo page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Make sure you display an iFrame, and hit the blue 'Play' button below the player. On desktop browsers, this works fine, but fails on an iOS7 iPad.

I need the 'playVideo()' command to control a chromeless player (no controls). Any ideas?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad

Comment: I created a new discussion to figure out how to detect when you should not all playVideo(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895492/detect-if-browser-supports-autoplay-of-embedded-media-youtube-playvideo-and

Answer (score 1):

Try the autoplay feature if hitting the big red button is not a compulsion, i have done so by adding "**event.target.playVideo();**" to the onReady function in the embeded HTML body. My player shows the big red button and starts itself immediately. I have used the latest ios helper availble on GitHub [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper). It is also mentioned on the google developers site [Using the YouTube Helper Library to embed YouTube videos in your iOS application](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#installation_manual)