# iPad Audio Element

Tags: html, ipad, audio

So, I remember working on a project last year and running into this same issue - not being able to autoplay a video on an ipad since Apple is concerned with data usage charges. As silly as this problem seems, it keeps popping up again and again and has caused a major stoppage in the current project I'm working on (it seems to always come down to hacking away to make things work on the ipad now).

Anyway, the current issue is with Audio tags. I've built an HTML5/JS game engine and all works beautifully across all browsers, phones and tablets, but I'm dynamically creating audio elements for sound effects and scenery music.

Last I understood, the workaround was to have a single element that the user plays once, then you can dynamically change the src to be whatever you like - this obviously won't work in my case since a user can generate hundreds of different sound effects under different conditions. I've even seen some horrible "silent noise" hacks to work around this issue...

Not sure if anyone is going to request seeing code... but I'm just appending an audio tag with autoplay and a src. Works great everywhere, hoping that someone has a simple workaround (or perhaps Apple was smart enough to include a setting in the OS to allow for autoplaying?)

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I understand `autoplay` attribute is a common pitfall for all media elements in iOS. Perhaps this link will help - [Can you autoplay HTML5 videos on the iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad)

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much the answers I've come across in the past and was hoping that something new had developed.