# Is it possible to autoplay HTML5 video on iOS 6 and earlier

Tags: javascript, ios, html, html5-video

I want to autoplay HTML5 video on iOS devices. I searched on google and here on stackoverflow for this. I found many answers (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad) ) saying that it is not possible to autoplay video on iOS 6.1 and later. Therefore it is possible to autoplay video on iOS 6.0 and earlier. But I don't know how can I do that.

Will this work on iOS 6.0 and earlier?

`<body onload="document.myMovie.play()">`

Comment: Try this http://stanko.github.io/html-canvas-video-player/ ... but u can't use autoplay and audio in the same time

Answer (score 0):

I don't idea avout iOS but you can try

`<video controls autoplay> //autoplay commad play your video automatically after load.
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>`