# Why HTML5 video doesn't play in IOS 8 WebApp(webview)?

Tags: ios, html, html5-video, ios8, iphone-standalone-web-app

Simple HTML5 video plays on safari browser. but after adding it to home screen(Standalone WebApp), it doesn't work. It is working on iOS7 but stopped working on iOS8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>HTML5 Video Standalone Test</title>
    <style>
    body{
        margin:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video src="http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v" autoplay="autoplay" controls="true" webkit-playsinline />
</body>
</html>
```

Please help. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: AFAIK, iOS blocks `autoplay` and allows to play video only bu user action. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad. Probably, this also may help: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/137599/html5-video-autoplay-on-ios#answer-274379

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn HTML5 Video doesn't work anymore on iOS8 standalone webapp for me.

Comment: for me too, It does not work anymore...

<div style="height:100%;">
<video x-webkit-airplay="allow" autoplay controls="" style="width: 100%; height: 90%;"><source src="@video_url@" /></video>\
</div>

Comment: It isn't just failing with auto play, it fails with standard "tap to play" manual initiation of video. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972600/ios-8-embedded-youtube-in-html-web-app-fails?noredirect=1

Comment: Just tested on iOS 8.2 beta and can confirm that it still is NOT fixed.

Comment: Not working on iOS 8.1.2 either.

Comment: Not working on iOS 8.3beta either. :-(

Comment: iOS 8.3 fixes the bug. Great new.

Comment: Still not working on 8.1.3! Any workaround this issue?

Answer (score 17):

Video playback is broken on standalone applications in IOS 8.0.2

Comment: Video and Audio tags are broken in iOS 8.0.2 web app

Comment: Is there an official source that confirms this claim?

Comment: Video playback is not working in cordova apps as well. Nothing happens after tap on play button. Hopefully they'll fix it soon.

Comment: After looking into this once again, I've figured that Angular policies was the problem in my case. Now I can confirm that embedded <video> is working in cordova app.

Comment: My worst fears comfirmed - but thanks for confirming. This is really awful.

Comment: Still broken in ios 8.1.2. Nice repro case available at http://tests.mikeditum.co.uk/iPad/video_playback.html. I have reported it to apple

Comment: On iOS 8.0.2 and 8.1.2 happens for Audio as well. Works like a charm on regular Safari and Chrome, either crashes on desktop or not playing at all, and only plays all playbacks on unload.

Comment: Confirming upgrade to 8.3 fixes Audio on desktop as well.

Comment: Finally fixed on IOS 9

Answer (score 7):

Looks like iOS 8.3 fixes this issue. I have a standalone web app that uses an audio element, and it's working as expected now. FINALLY!

Comment: I've tried a webview app with embedde videos on an ipad and did not work on **ios 8.3**. Do you have any references to the bugfix?

Comment: I can confirm video playback in a standalone webapp works in iOS 8.3, while it didn't work in 8.2.

Answer (score 6):

## Confirming

#### Packaged cordova App cannot load video

Added:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
```

to `config.xml` and

```
webkit-playsinline
```

to the `video` element.

The UI says video is `Loading`, while `video.networkStatus` remains `2` (`NETWORK_LOADING`) and `video.readyState` `0` (`HAVE_NOTHING`)

#### Safari playback works

#### Home screen launcher playback does not work

For the same webapp that worked in ios Safari, the homescreen version does **not** play videos either, and crashes the webapp when trying to change the source of the `video`.

I don't like apple :|

Comment: Confirming that, as of this comment, changing the source of a video in a home-screen web-app crashes the app.

Answer (score 2):

I have two apps that use HTML5 video. One stopped working, the other not. There were two differences:

- The one that still works added the source tags to the video tag AFTER adding the video tag to the DOM.
- The app that still works has autoplay set to false (`<video autoplay="false">...</video>`)

The first one made no difference, the second one made the app work again.

Comment: I added autoplayy="flase" and still the webApp crashes as soon as i click the play button! I tested it on ios 8.1.3 . Could you tell me how did you create the play button that worked ?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround for the audio not working. I can't really explain why this fix is working, but it is.

Here's what my old code looked like:

```
// Create the audio tag
var sprite = document.createElement('audio');
var id = document.createAttribute('id');
id.nodeValue = 'audio_sprite';
var src = document.createAttribute('src');
src.nodeValue = 'my-audio-sprite.mp3';

sprite.setAttributeNode( id );
sprite.setAttributeNode( src );

// Add it to the DOM
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild( sprite );

// Play/Pause to load the audio.
sprite.play();
sprite.pause();
```

Here's what I'm doing now.

```
// Grab an existing DOM element and create an audio tag.
var body = document.getElementById('hover');
body.innerHTML += '<audio id="audio_sprite"><p>Audio not supported</p></audio>';

// Apply the SRC to the audio tag.
// Q: Why don't we just do that in the step above?
// A: I'm not really sure why, but iOS8 doesn't like it. Sorry this is so ugly.
var sprite = document.getElementById( 'audio_sprite' );
sprite.src = 'my-audio-sprite.mp3';

// Once the metadata is loaded, call play/pause so we can play the audio later.
sprite.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    sprite.play();
    sprite.pause();
});
```

In my mind, both should work however, in practice, only the second one does for iOS8. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: cannot confirm on iOS 7.1 - doesn't work after "Add To Home Screen"

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by finding the video element, then creating a source element in script (not in the html) - strange I know:

```
var video = document.getElementById('theVideo');
var source = document.createElement('source');

source.src = fileLocation
source.type = "video/mp4"

video.appendChild( source );
video.load();
```

I also accept this is an old issue, but I came across it as I was testing on an iPad that has iOS 8.0.2 installed and it caught me out for a day.

Comment: i tried  $(source).attr('src', myfile);player.load();
                player.webkitEnterFullscreen();
                player.play(); but webApp crashed on ios 8.1.3 . could you tell me what i am doing wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for reply . source is: var source = document.getElementById('mp4'); I even tried your exact code and sending the video url via this hyperlink <a href="javascript:playvideo('http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4','./test.png')">test</a></br> But the webApp Crashes! could you post a demo in jsfiddle that didn't crash the app?

Comment: What crash do you get? - for example the video file you've posted is a 404

Comment: The webApp closes instead of playing the video. The example url is http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4