# Youtube iframe api not opening ios native video player - webapp

Tags: web-applications, youtube, youtube-api, ios8, iphone-web-app

Have an web app were I use the youtube iFrame api.

Using the method loadVideoById works fine in iOS 6 and 7, it opens the native iOS video player and plays the video but the same doesn't happen on iOS 8.0.2. The event state change accordingly but the native video player doesn't open.

I've run out of ideas to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same problem with our webapp, seems to be an issue with the latest iOS and from the research we've done, we'll have to sit on our hands till Apple comes out with an update. Seems to include iframes, HTML5 video player, videoJS.

Possible cause/discussion: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/9/25/IndexedDB-on-iOS-8--Broken-Bad

Related issue: [Why HTML5 video doesn't play in IOS 8 WebApp(webview)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972362/why-html5-video-doesnt-play-in-ios-8-webappwebview)

Related issue: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/8612598-ios-web-app-capable-incompatibility-videos-won-t-play

Will post back if we discover a workaround.

Comment: We might have come up with a solution. It seems that if we use HTTPS on our Apps the videos play fine on iOS8 so we are currently merging everything to HTTPS.
Probably some security update on safari on iOS8, because on iOS7 it works flawlessly (same code)

Comment: This solution is not working for us, we can still not play fullscreen video from our app