# iframe does not work on iPhone when the webpage is saved to homepage

Tags: html, ios, iframe, youtube, html5-video

I have a video player on a webpage using an iframe and javascript (parts of the code shown below). Everything works fine on my laptop and on safari on an iPad with iOS8. However if I add the webpage to the homescreen and open the webpage from the homescreen, the video won't load. I made a quick jsbin with everything and it works on iOS 8 from the homescreen so it shouldn't be a problem with the code itself. Is there anything differently that safari does when the link is opened from the homepage?

html:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="320" height="192" id="YouTubePlayer">
</iframe>
```

javscript:

```
url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/5JJ983bxFGU';
$('#YouTubePlayer').attr({
        src: url
})
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972362/why-html5-video-doesnt-play-in-ios-8-webappwebview , same problem.