# How to prevent a youtube iframe to redirect from Standalone App to Youtube App?

Tags: html, ios, iframe, youtube, tablet

I have a web magazine developed in [reveal js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/). Of course the user can decide to create a shortcut for his/her own smartphone or tablet, creating a standalone application, that's not opened in the normal browser, with url bar, navigation commands, etc..

And to do this, I use this code

```
<!-- CAPABLE FOR APPLE DEVICES -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="">
```

Everything works fine, except when I swipe to a page that has in its content a youtube iframe.
In this scenario, what happens it's a redirection from my standalone application browser to youtube application.
And it does not happen in all the smartphones / tablet, but for example I noticed that on iPad 3 with not the last version of iOS (currently 8.3) I got this redirection, but with an iPad 3 with an older iOS version (7.0.2) the iframe of youtube is displayed inside my standalone application.

Does somebody has an idea about this issue?

Comment: apparently it's an Apple bug, read this [article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6558443)

Comment: and to give a quick solution, this is the way the youtube iframe should be written: `<iframe width="760" height="570" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ch2Dw7lMg_w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` - watch out on the no coockie part, everything is there!