# Writing text over IOS native video player with javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video, video.js

I am building a PHONEGAP app which display video using HTML5 & VIDEOJS. 
Unfortunately I found that controlling video displayed on IOS devices very frustrating.

I understand that I am unable to touch the volume of the video on **ANY** IOS device. 
I believe this is why VIDEOJS don't even show the volume & mute controls on IPAD (please correct me if I am wrong).

Now I tried adding text overlay to the video. 
It works fine on IPAD but is there a way to do it over IOS native video player which is loaded automatically on IPHONEs?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was changed after the comment from @user2299401

PhoneGap uses a UIWebView on IOS and in an app it's possible to play the video inline although the support seems to be broken according to the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972362/why-html5-video-doesnt-play-in-ios-8-webappwebview)

To do that you need to do the following:

1. add `<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>` to the ios platform config of your config.xml
2. add `webkit-playsinline` to video tag.

Playing the video inline allows you to add overlays on top of it.

Comment: As far as I know Phonegap doesn't use Safari but webkit which power both Safari & chrome. So it must be a feature of the IOS regardless of the browser being used.