# HTML 5 Video's Audio Muted in iOS 10 Web Apps

Tags: ios, html, html5-video, ios10, iphone-standalone-web-app

Audio in HMTL5 video works fine in Safari on iOS 10.3.1 on iPhone, though it doesn't in standalone web apps (same html code & video file). Video play is fine. Just no sound.

There are a few other related discussions in the past, eg, [Why HTML5 video doesn't play in IOS 8 WebApp(webview)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972362/why-html5-video-doesnt-play-in-ios-8-webappwebview). I tested on iOS 10 using the html provided by [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972362/why-html5-video-doesnt-play-in-ios-8-webappwebview).

Not sure whether it is a new bug introduced in iOS 10, or a bug that has never been fixed by Apple since earlier versions. Does anyone experience this issue? Are there any workarounds? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I googled all over the place. Then I realized what was causing the problem: I had the physical "soft mute" switch (next to the volume buttons) on my iPad turned on. Infuriatingly, this muted the volume on web apps, but not Safari web pages.