# MP3 Link not working on iPhone/iOS

Tags: html, ios, iphone, mp3, html5-audio

Good afternoon, I created a website for an online radio station. At the top there is an MP3 link, which starts automatically.

However on my iPhone the radio/MP3 does not work. do I need to save it as a different format?

```html
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://93.190.141.15:7003/live?type=.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

*** Update ***
After searching the internet, i located jplayer.org.
Will this rectify the iOS concern.
It says that it is compatible with Mobile Safari: iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the issue is the `autoplay` feature. Try loading the radio directly in your browser to see if it works

Comment: Hello Aziz, i tried that and it works. would you suggest removing autoplay.

Comment: It seems to be an Apple philosophy where they do not allow any media to autoplay unless a user initiates it.

Answer (score 0):

File MIME type was not specified while uploading and as a result it is being returned as binary/octet-stream. The desktop browsers are smart enough to overcome this, but the mobile browsers are not. The answer to the above question is therefore to set the MIME type for the relevant file upon writing to GCS.

Hope, this help ! ;)

Comment: That might solve the format problem, however, I just found out that Safari browser in mobile devices does not allow autoplay - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066062/autoplay-html5-audio-player-on-mobile-browsers

Comment: Following on from this issue, does anyone know if there is a work around. I found this on the Apple developer page. https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html