# Dailymotion SDK Autoplay not working, as well as no method to stop video

Tags: android, webview, dailymotion-api

I am trying to develop an app that has one Activity and a Fragment inside that Activity
i have integrated Dailymotion SDK for android from github and used it with DMWebVideoView

it is specified in the API documentation that to Auto Play
You can make the video to start as soon as the player is loaded. To do so, either call `setAutoPlay(true)` before setting the id of your video or call `setVideoId(, true)`, but actually the method in the SDK is `setAutoPlaying(boolean autoPlay)`.
i have referred all the possible solutions from stackoverflow but could not find a working solution.
is there any another way to make Auto Play work?
i also want to stop the video from DMWebVideoView
i have used the following methods

```
mVideoView.setAutoPlaying(true);
mVideoView.setVideoId(VIDEO_ID);
```

i have also tried this by doing

```
mVideoView.setVideoId(VIDEO_ID, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

on Player API documentation about autoplay parameter,

> Starts the playback of the video automatically after the player load
>   (defaults to 0). Note: this parameter may not work on some mobile OS
>   versions as most mobile devices prevent the video from autoplaying to
>   save user's bandwidth.

Mobile video autoplay is often disabled (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad))

Comment: Thanks, but i kept it as it was, i had already gone through these line a month ago. but thanks anyways