# Jquery doesn't play sound in iphone

Tags: jquery

the sound works fine with desktop browsers but doesn't work in iPhone.

```
$('<audio id="notification_sound"><source src="sounds/notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="sounds/notify.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>').appendTo('body');
```

tried many different ways but no luck

Comment: How about you try just placing the `<audio>` tag in by itself. Does your phone's browser support the HTML5 tag?

Comment: If you're expecting automatic playback, iOS doesn't allow automatic playback of media as of iOS 6.1 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad).