# How did the background video on the website of "http://www.exodusgodsandkings.com" autoplay on the iPad?

Tags: html, css, ipad, video.js, autoplay

How did the **background video** on the website of **"http://www.exodusgodsandkings.com"** **autoplay** on the **iPad**?

Answer (score 0):

using javascript onload function for example

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('Yourid').play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is disabled on ipad and iphones by apple. see post [Can you autoplay HTML5 videos on the iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad).

As a caveat I have started using a slide show of the individual frames displayed on mobile devices as an alternative and appended the .play(); to the close button on a shadowbox of a cta on the page with the background video. This is not perfect but it is a pretty elegant solution.