# HTML5 audio issue with Mobile Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html, jquery-ui

I have created a Simon Game here on Codepen: http://codepen.io/nalexiou/pen/rOaQOK

On the desktop, the audio/sound is playing fine. However, when I visit the site using my iPhone's Safari, the sound will not play.

I call the play() method on the sound variables (green, red, etc.) via this jQueryUI code:

```
......
 $('.' + items[0]).addClass('active', speed, function() {
    obj[items[0]].play();}).removeClass('active', speed, 
    function() {
    nextItemActivate(items.slice(1));
 });
......
```

However, if I trigger the play() methods first like this:

```
$('.test').on('click', function() {
  green.play();
  red.play();
  yellow.play();
  blue.play();
})
```

then the my `addClass` code does play the sounds.

Could this issue be related with the jQueryUI library or is there something special I need to consider for the Mobile Safari browser?

Thank you.

Comment: All iOs devices wait for a user interaction play video, sound or etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the article from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

By the way, you can't use autoplay or trig to play function video or audio because of:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12496184/2686143

Comment: Thanks for the info @Guvenckardas. What is confusing is that in both cases in my code, the play method is triggered initially by a click event (pressing Start/Replay or Play All Sounds) by the user. Thus, I am not really sure why does one function behaves differently than the other one.

Comment: Actually, there is not a real different behaviour. Just play function for video or audio not working. You know that, all media activities are managed in QuickTime player  for iOs so it can control all activities.

Comment: Do you want to play all sounds in the same time?

Comment: I do not need to - I just created that button/scenario to test/compare against the Start/Replay button that won't play the sounds.