# How to autoplay HTML5 <video> and <audio> tags on iOS ?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio, video

My team and I are tying to make a web application autoplay HTML5 video/audio tags on **iPad**. So far no luck after many attempts with **CSS** and **JavaScript**.

> The question is: **What other option is there to make it autoplay ?**

I'm thinking native app with integrated browser with **iOS API** calls to **simulate a touch/click** and thus making the video/audio tags autoplay.

**Is it possible and if  yes, how and with which iOS version ?**

Thanks

Comment: You need a contractor, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: So you're saying that is it possible ? Could you elaborate please ?

Comment: I think my comment answers that question.

Comment: Try this http://stanko.github.io/html-canvas-video-player/ ... but u can't use autoplay and audio in the same time

Comment: This was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad/39777974#39777974

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you autoplay HTML5 videos on the iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad)

Comment: opera mini in ios supports autoplay by default, while chrome, firefox and safari does not and have not offering options to turn on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't auto-play videos and audios on iOS in normal mode, you may use trick like simulate user input to auto-play videos and audios.

[Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not.

This plays the movie: `<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="document.myMovie.play()">`

This does nothing on iOS: `<body onload="document.myMovie.play()">`

Comment: Indeed. I had already seen iOS restrictions. Would you know if it's possible with a native app + embedded browser ?

Comment: sorry for late response. I think the best way is simulate the user touch, i saw the solution before for this, if i found it i will send it here.

Comment: And the only way to do that is with a native app from what I've found. That's how Facebook got their video autoplay.

Answer (score -1):

Have you found solution for autoplay video on iOS device? If not, I've just find a solution [here, you can use WeChat of iPhone to open it](http://gaoshanyu.github.io/blog/video) (just support WeChat of iPhone but not support iPad WeChat), it use video.js player, related code as below:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="auto" webkit-playsinline="true" x-webkit-airplay="true" width="750" height="460" poster="" data-setup="{}">
```

It also has solution for support video play without full screen on iOS/Android/PC.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look during a break. I'm working on other projects now.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Bouhier, Sorry, I have misstaked this. It just support iPhone  WeChat to autoplay, but not support Safari of iPhone. I've edited my answer to correct. Sorry for confuse.