# HTML5 Video autoplay attribute don't work on ios version 9

Tags: ios, iphone, html, html5-video

is there a solution for an ios autoplay onload for ios version 9.
I'm using

```
<video autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true" playsinline="true" >
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

and this work well on most devices.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945273/how-to-autoplay-html5-video-and-audio-tags-on-ios

Comment: @PiyushPatel thanks a lot, that was very helpful