# HTML5 Video Autoplay on Mobile Devices

Tags: html, video, mobile

- The question is not "Is it possible"? I know the mobile browsers can not autoplay html5 videos but, here i have an example of autoplaying.

Please explain to the world how is possible that!

Here the example: http://misc.teads.tv/us/demo/InReadWeltDemo2/index.html#232943677

And now? ;-)

Comment: Some research. Result: Its device dependent: Have a look at this older question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12496184/4676259 Grtz

Comment: If you see the example i posted then you will understand it is possible...

Answer (score 0):

You probably might have found this by now. But if not, then that video is triggered by the user's touch (**window.touchStart**) event. As soon as the user touches the screen to click/scroll, the video element's **.play()** is triggered.

You could try opening the url in any mobile-browser that does not support touch events to see that the video does not play until you click on it.