# Play two vimeo videos at the same time on ios?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-ios

Using froogaloop (the js api provided by vimeo) I was able to play two videos at the same time on desktop and android phone but this isn't working on ipad.

It's a video of someone commenting the first video so I also need the first video to be muted (also ok on desktop and android phone).

On ipad, it seems like the first video shortly enters the playing state and stops when the second starts, as if there were an hard-coded limitation on the player that prevent both videos from playing at the same time. 
Ipad is also the only platform where I see the "undock" button, which could explain the hard limitation.

Is there a way to play 2 videos at the same time, one muted, the other at full volume ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, vimeo has relased its new api recently and froogalops won't be maintained anymore, yet still working. I' don't know wether this release brings any changes in respect of ios

Second, your question is not super clear to me, as it seem you manage to do what you wanted, except on ipad (what ios version and what about other ios devices), while your title and your bottom line is

> Is there a way to play 2 videos at the same time, one muted, the other at full volume ?

and not  ? Is there a way to play two vimeo video at the same time on ipad or ios ?

Third, vimeo provides the posibility to add `autopause=0` in the url of your embeded video, this prevent the vimeo video curently playing to be paused when another one is started. 
It works on desktop and android but haven't tried the behaviour on ipad yet as Ì don't have one in hand at the moment.

Finally, after some seach, it seems that this question may be asked regarding ios at large, and not solely ipad, and in this respect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad) post might be usefull for you

Not sure if it helps, as your post is 7 month old, but if you provide your code I may give a second try.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the question title to make it clear. Unfortunately I cannot test the new vimeo api as I'm not working on this project anymore. But since you pointed out the new api available, I consider this answer correct.