# How to autoplay mobile web video iOS (see demo)

Tags: javascript, ios, ffmpeg, mobile-safari

Is there any library that sequences images and audio playback? I'm guessing that's the only way this could work..

Which picture formats would work best? I'm guessing that pictures wouldn't be as compressed as a video, but this example loads instantly for me:

[Demo: Autoplay Inline Video iOS](https://www.easy-bits.com/iphone-inline-video-autostart?tag=tears-of-steel)

Planning to just convert the video with ffmpeg. Any knowledge and advice would be great before I get started. Thanks

Comment: Is this for mobile web? Or native applications?

Comment: it's for mobile web, the iOS safari browser

Answer (score 0):

I believe that since iOS 6.1 you can no longer autoplay videos.

Referring to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad)

> "Apple has made the decision to disable the automatic playing of video on iOS devices, through both script and attribute implementations.
>
> In Safari, on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and auto-play are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it." - [Apple documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

Comment: Yea but there are workarounds, somehow. I worked in ad tech and we were thinking to sequence images. The link I sent shows working video