# User action required on every play() call for html5 video on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video

For mobile devices, it seems user action such as a click/touch is needed in order to play video (or perhaps audio too) - specifically before calling the play() method on a video element is successful.

See for example [Can you autoplay HTML5 videos on the iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad)

However, is that for *every* play() or just the first? i.e. can I have a "start" button which quickly calls play() and pause() on a video element, and then subsequent play() on that video element will not be via user action but rather some other internal logic down the line?

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad

Comment: Gives weight to the question- added it in, thanks!