# Stop background video from downloading when used in Video tag (HTML5) for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, video, fullpage.js

I am using FullPage.js script on few pages of website to embed video as background.

Something similar to this script http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/videoBackground.html

With only difference is that my videos are between  3MB - 7MB in size. It works fine on desktop and same page are slow to download on Mobile devices as it also download the video along with the webpage.

Is there any built in feature that will stop video from downloading on mobile devices Other than using JavaScript to remove the `src="video1.mp4"`

```
<video autoplay loop muted controls="false" id="myVideo">
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Further to this when i test same web  pingdom.com website it download the same video file multiple time which increase the page size. This i have noticed only with this website speed test platform. While when i test using Firebug it download video file only once.

https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/coQYIA/http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/videoBackground.html

Comment: you could possibly use CSS media queries to control it, but would need some experimentation. Javascript - a library like http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ - would certainly be easier

Comment: The second link is broken.
(https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/coQYIA/http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/videoBackground.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question?
[Stop video from loading in background on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561261)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know videos won't autoplay in iOS. Not sure how it works on other devices or OS but I would say they are not downloaded in iOS devices.

For the rest, I guess you can make use of the callback `afterResponsive` which will fire once the page enters in responsive mode or comes out of it.
Meaning you can detect when you are in a "mobile device" by using this method and then do whatever you want to do.

More info [in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterresponsiveisresponsive).

## UPDATE

It seems that from iOS 10 restrictions on autoplay has been removed to certain videos with no audio.
[Check this other answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad)

Comment: I am my self confused with this as it autoplay video on one of the page on iPad but not the other page video code is identical on all other pages. I even cleared all the cache even used private browser session but it keeps happening for this one page only.