# Stop video from loading in background on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, html5-video

I have a video header that I only want to play on desktop, with a static image header on mobile.  I can hide the video on mobile and it looks like it works fine, but the video is still being loaded in the background and slowing the page load.  How can I stop the video from loading at all on mobile.

```
<video id="bgvid" class="hidden-xs ">    
  <source type="video/mp4" src="myvideo.mp4"></source>
</video>

<img alt="" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" src="myimage.jpg" class="visible-xs" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're setting visibility via CSS, or in earlier JS code, you can do something like this:

1. Include `data-src` attributes instead of `src` on your video elements. No src to load if we don't need to.
2. *If* the video is visible, copy `data-src` to `src`
3. Now call `.load()` on the `video` element, to pick up the new values.

```js
$(
  function() {
    const bgv = $('#bgvid');

    if (bgv.is(':visible')) {
      $('source', bgv).each(
        function() {
          const el = $(this);
          el.attr('src', el.data('src'));
        }
      );

      bgv[0].load();
    }
  }
)
```

```css
.hidden-xs {
  display: none;
}

/* dummy criterion for demo purposes */
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video id="bgvid" class="hidden-xs " controls>
  <source type="video/mp4" data-src="https://archive.org/download/UNIVAC-AD-2/UNIVAC2_512kb.mp4">
  <source type="video/ogg" data-src="https://archive.org/download/UNIVAC-AD-2/UNIVAC2.ogv">
</video>
```

Or, without jQuery:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const bgv = document.getElementById("bgvid");

  // what jQuery checks under the hood
  const visible = bgv.offsetWidth ||
    bgv.offsetHeight ||
    bgv.getClientRects().length;

  if (visible) {
    const children = bgv.getElementsByTagName("source");

    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
      children[i].src = children[i].dataset.src;
    }
  }

  bgv.load();
});
```

```css
.hidden-xs {
  display: none;
}

/* dummy criterion for demo purposes */

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="bgvid" class="hidden-xs" controls>
  <source type="video/mp4" data-src="https://archive.org/download/UNIVAC-AD-2/UNIVAC2_512kb.mp4">
  <source type="video/ogg" data-src="https://archive.org/download/UNIVAC-AD-2/UNIVAC2.ogv">
</video>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set `<video>` `poster` attribute value to path to image file. At `load` event of `window` check conditions to determine whether or not to set `.src` of `<video>` element to path to video file.

```
<video poster="myimage.jpg"></video>
```

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (/* conditions */ window.innerWidth > 480) 
    document.querySelector("video").src = "myvideo.mp4";
}
```

Comment: This solution always displays the poster image.

Comment: @HarryRobinsob Yes, poster image is displayed until user or `javascript` begins playback of video.

Answer (score 3):

**This solution works for me**. You can change the number "767" to any maximum pixel width of a device you would like the video not to display on. Keep in mind that this will remove all videos from mobile devices. However, you can also use a class or ID of the video tag; you just need to change the script for remove().

**Script code in header:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
   if($(window).width() <= 767){

    $( "video" ).remove();
   }
});

</script>
```

**In Body of Document:**

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay class="fullscreen-bg__video">
            <source src="http://yoururl.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, but be aware that posts including an **unsolicited commercial advertisement** can get deleted as spam. For more see [What is the exact definition of “spam” for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638). I've edited that portion out for now.

Comment: This is the only solution I've come across to *silently* prevent video(s) from *even loading* on "small" devices/mobiles.
As I haven't tried it, I cannot confirm for sure that it works, but it certainly looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop multiple videos and mute them as well with fallback img on mobile this should help out

```js
const video = document.querySelectorAll('video')
              video.forEach(data=>{
                data.volume = 0 //mute video
                console.log(data);
                  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
                      data.autoplay=false;
                  } else {
                      data.play();
                  }
                })
```