# Revolution Slider video not play in iPhone

Tags: php, html, iphone, wordpress

I use the video as a background. The background works well everywhere except the iPhone. I deleted the audio track, but it does not help. How can I play video on iPhone?

**PHP CODE**

```
<!-- BACKGROUND VIDEO LAYER -->
        <div class="rs-background-video-layer" 
            data-forcerewind="on" 
            data-volume="mute" 
            data-videowidth="100%" 
            data-videoheight="100%" 
            data-videomp4="/wp-content/themes/SCALE/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Working.mp4 "   
            data-videopreload="auto" 
            data-videoloop="loopandnoslidestop" 
            data-forceCover="1" 
            data-aspectratio="16:9" 
            data-autoplay="true" 
            data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that while the autoplay restriction is lifted for non-audio videos, if you have it in other versions there could be a conflict. You could try adding the property 'muted' or try the workaround suggested here: [Can you autoplay HTML5 videos on the iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496144/can-you-autoplay-html5-videos-on-the-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize and compress your video to 7mb, then it may start to play.

It helped me, and for desktop I kept full video length.