# Changing mediasource whith javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I ran into a little problem right now and i can't find a solution.

HTML:

```
<video id="vid" controls >
<source src=".mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="HEYE.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ChangeVideo(){
 if(click%2 == 0){
    document.getElementById('vid').src="Troll.mp4";
    click++;
 }else{
    document.getElementById('vid').src="HEYE.mp4";
    click++;
 }
}
```

Button:

```
<button onclick="ChangeVideo()">Change video</button>
```

the problem is that i dont get it to change video when i click the button.

My to videos in my map is named "HEYE.mp4" and "Troll.mp4"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change video being played in HTML5 video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772409/change-video-being-played-in-html5-video)

Answer (score 1):

```
function ChangeVideo(){
    var vid = document.getElementById('vid');
    vid.src = click%2 ? "HEYE.mp4" : "Troll.mp4";
    vid.load();
    vid.play();
    click++;
}
```